# Varnish / NGINX time based restrictions

Tags: php, mysql, apache, nginx, varnish

I'm trying to implement time and geo-location based restrictions for our CMS. Below is what the current setup looks like

- **Nginx (Port: 443):** For SSL termination and URL manipulation
- **Varnish (Port: 80):** To cache dynamic content from the backend
- **Apache, PHP, MySQL:** Custom CMS runs on this stack

The requirement is such that for a certain time period, traffic from a specific country cannot access a particular URL / category but traffic from the rest of the world can access the same URL / category without any restriction.

The geo-location part doesn't seem daunting but I have not been able to find anything about restricting traffic based on the time.

Sure, I can set up two varnish or nginx configurations, one with the restrictions one without, have a cron job replace the physical files based on when I want what done but I was hoping for a cleaner solution.

I understand that all this can be handled with PHP but I cannot remove Varnish from the stack, I'd have to put in 5-6 servers to handle the load and that'll add cost that I cannot justify.

Help?

Comment: What about a script that updates your NGINX config on a schedule?

Comment: You can do this time based restriction by HAProxy, also you can do the `restriction/ssl termination/url manipulation/cache` all in one app: https://github.com/jiangwenyuan/nuster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `now` in varnish, and the do a regex on the date in varnish to produce 403 or whatever

here is a sample `varnishtest`  case showing of on how to use `now`

```
varnishtest "Time Gate"

server s1 {
       rxreq
       txresp

} -start

varnish v1 -vcl+backend {
    import std;

    sub vcl_recv {
        //now is in RFC format: Thu, 26 Apr 2018 08:40:22 GMT
        //set it in a "ghost header" to convert it to a STRING otherwise it is a TIME
        // and regex won't work
        set req.http.now_string = now;

        //Check the hour
        if(req.http.now_string ~ "^.* [0-9]{4} 08") {
              // Do stuff when its 08:xx
        } else {
             // Otherwise do something else.
        }


    }

    sub vcl_deliver {
        set resp.http.x-forwarded-for = client.ip;
        set resp.http.now_string = req.http.now_string;
    }
} -start

client c1 {
    txreq  -url "/1"
    rxresp
    expect resp.http.now_string ~  "2018"


} -run
```

about the geo-protection you can also do this in varnish with https://github.com/varnish/libvmod-geoip this vmod. (haven't testet this personally)